# Updating python on ec2 instance

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, python-2.7, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

Currently in progress of some updates on my webapp. One issue I am running into would be updating from python 2.7 to python 3.6. I found that creating a new virtualenv would create a whole new folder where I am thinking I have to copy everything from my previous directory to the new one?

I am thinking there is an easier way to do this that I am not coming across.

Thanks ahead of time

Comment: Which instance has only python 2? I think all of new have python 3 as well.

Comment: My instance is Ubuntu 16.04.6 @Marcin

Comment: Have you tried any of tutorials on how to install python 3 on ubuntu 16.04, e.g. [this](http://devopspy.com/python/install-python-3-6-ubuntu-lts/)?

Comment: I have python 3 installed.. Looks like my webapp is having troubles finding python now

Comment: Is there possibly a way I could link my webapp to python3

Comment: I don't know what is your webapp, what errors do you get? Your question does not provide such information.

Comment: Now getting `--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---`